# Run node.js as secure server and use webRTC when IIS is using port 443?

Tags: node.js, https, streaming, webrtc

I am trying to use `webRTC` to stream audio from a client to Node.js.
The problem is: `webRTC` does not work on HTTP, only HTTPS. So - My IIS is using this port. I tried establishing my Node.js to listen to port 443:

### First attempt: Use https.createServer, over port 9001:

**Node.JS script:**

```
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('../cert/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('../cert/server.crt')

};
var httpsserver = https.createServer(options).listen(443);
var server = binaryServer({ server: httpsserver, port: 443 });
```

**Client script:**

```
client = new BinaryClient('ws://example.com:443');
```

I'm getting this error in my node script, so my first question is: Is this because port 443 is being used by my IIS?

> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^
>
> Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:443 at Object.exports._errnoException
>   (util.js:1018:11) at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
>   at Server._listen2 (net.js:1249:19)

Having this error, I tried using a different port (9001).

---

### Second attempt: Use https.createServer, over port 9001:

**Client script:**

```
client = new BinaryClient('ws://example.com:9001');
```

When I try to connect from a client to the node.js server on 9001, because the site address is `https://example.com`, I'm getting this error in the **client**:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://example.com/page.aspx'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure
>   WebSocket endpoint 'ws://example.com:9001/'. This request has been
>   blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.

Because the error mentions using `wss://`, I tried the following.

---

### Third attempt: Use WSS://, over port 9001:

So, I switch the client to work with `WSS://`,

```
client = new BinaryClient('wss://example.com:9001');
```

but then, in the **client**, I get this error:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com:9001/' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Any ideas how can I run my node.js server on a srcure port, assuming my IIS uses port 443, and still be able to connect securly to a client, and use webRTC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome is allowing gUM/WebRTC from Secure origins only, i.e: page url should be https & all the subsequent requests from that page should be secure.

So we must use **wss://** as websocket url

It seems you are using self signed certificates,
Allow the certificate manually by entering the URL https://example.com:9001 in browser tab.

After opening the page you should get an error page, then you need to allow by clicking Advanced -> proceed.

If the page is not loaded, then u need to look into firewall or ip/dns of your server is reachable from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a web server running and serving secure requests then what is usually done is having that web server act as a reverse proxy for you Node application. That way you don't need to handle the certificates and you don't worry about port conflicts.

See this answers and links for more details:

- [SSL With node / IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958052/ssl-with-node-iis/42958289#42958289)